# Where are the messages sent by a Joomla contact form?

Tags: joomla, forms, contact-page

Where can we find the messages sent by the users using contact form in Joomla 2.5?

I just activated the contact us page in the menu. While testing it, after filling all the fields and submitting the form, I am getting the message that your request submitted successfully. As an admin, where can I find those messages? I am not receiving those messages as e-mail.

Comment: Which component are you using?

Answer (score 2):

They should get delivered to you by email.  It sounds like you may not have properly set up the "contact" for your contact form.    Here is a YouTube video tutorial that walks you through the entire process:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEK3JxqTxRQ